# In the long run, which is conserved, energy or momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

I think it is impossible to conserve both energy and momentum in the long run, in an independent system, because momentum depends on the 'sum of the velocities' whereas, kinetic energy depends on the 'sum of squares of the velocities'. Only in some arbitrary cases can this be possible. In the long run, energy alone is conserved. Conservation of momentum may require the condition that no other form of energy in that system can get converted into kinetic energy. Am I wrong?

Comment: Observable momentum may not be conserved - only in elastic collisions. But momentum gets transferred into molecular motion, heat, increased electromagnetic potentials, physical deformation, and so on. This is very important in categorising particle collisions, where many of them are elastic, but special ones like deep inelastic collisions tell us some change happened to the constituents.

Comment: @CriglCragl *"Observable momentum may not be conserved - only in elastic collisions."* You've gotten things mixed up. All collisions respect conservation of momentum. It is bulk kinetic energy that is only conserved in elastic collisions, and energy that is diverted into other channels in inelastic collisions.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you are wrong. It's not hard to conserve both energy and momentum. A system of $100$ particles has $300$ velocity components. Momentum and energy conservation are only $3+1 = 4$ constraints. It's hardly impossible to satisfy $4$ constraints given $300$ degrees of freedom. The only time this might be hard is with a single particle, but in that case the constraints are redundant.

However, you can be forgiven for making this mistake, because many great physicists of the past did as well. In the early days of mechanics there was great debate over whether momentum or energy was the true measure of [*vis viva*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis_viva), the "quantity of motion". But they had the disadvantage of not knowing that heat was energy as well.

Answer (score 2):

You  wrote:

> Conservation of momentum may require the condition that no other form of energy in that system can get converted into kinetic energy

Our physics theories use a much simpler requirement than that.

Let me discuss the following example: a high energy photon splits into a particle and an anti-particle. The bulk of the energy of the photon went into creating the particles in the first place, any remainder goes to kinetic energy of those particles. So that's a case of another form of energy being converted to kinetic energy.

In the physics theory of particle creation/annihilation it is built into the very mathematical structure that only the creation of *pairs* of particles is possible, in such a way that momentum is conserved. In the very mathematical structure there is no room for an event where a photon turns into a single particle.

A theory that allows the creation of a single particle would allow events in which momentum cannot be conserved. Theories like that will probably turn out to be wrong in multiple ways. Physicists don't even try theories like that.

Instead, theories are designed in such a way that events will only occur in ways that conserve momentum. Only if the theory meets that condition will it be regarded as a theory worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

Both conservation laws can be true at the same time - that just restricts which events that are possible in this World. And this is exactly what we see in experiments.

Of some reason this World always upholds both of these laws and make any other event adapt to "fit".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both energy and momentum are conserved in isolated systems. (So to put it bluntly, yes, you are wrong.)

What allows this to work is that energy can be converted from kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2}mv^2$) to other forms (which don't depend on $v$) and back. So the sum of squared velocities of the particles in a system can change, as long as the amount of non-kinetic energy changes to compensate.

But there is no such balancing procedure for momentum. In an isolated system, the velocities are only allowed to change in a way such that their sum remains constant. The sum of their squares might go up or down as mentioned above, but the sum of the velocities themselves must remain constant.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong. But the actual problem is that it is not latest wronged theory. All theories are wronged in a time ordered fashion throughout history. you need the current way of thinking or the one wronged just before it. And that is the Truth.

There was not long ago a lady called [Emmy Noether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). The link is to Noether's Theorem about local continuous symmetry and a conserved current.

Your question asks for that answer.

I'll give you a restricted answer because I am kind:

If in the long run you mean uniform run in time direction exclusively, then that you would be correct, to check if in the system you are considering, Energy, is conserved, or it is not.

If you mean uniform run in some spatial direction exclusively it is momentum you need to check if yes or no. But don't look around because then it is a special relativity.

If it is uniform angular motion then you have gone far enough without Einstein and you need to acquire a little Einstein gravity.

Finally: Classical mechanics can still be awesome (It always was): [Hamilton's Formulation of Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics)

**REGARDING QUANTUM PARTICLES:**

It is a very abstract an mathematical realm. At the same time, in that realm they do not value their own theories, for when they are Falsified by their own work in a mathematical sense they keep doing mathematics with it until they can get it experimented, and then they take the data and go on with the math, and iterate experimentally and on and on. A logical infinity in motion, it appears. But, the ways out they find are pretty beautiful in an artistic sense.